# Single Sign On for one Rails application on many domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on

We are having one application that runs on one base domain. Application resolves where the traffic is coming, which means we have multiple domains (www.example.com, www.something.com...), but in essence it is one application. One of the controllers resolves the domain name.

Problem we are facing is Single Sign On. How to create SSO for all of the existing and future domains that will be added. We need when the user is logged on one domain, to be automatically logged on all of them. Is there some common practice how to fix that problem?

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: This question was already answered in Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274384/how-can-i-share-user-sessions-across-multiple-domains-using-rails

Comment: Application we use is on different domains. It is not a.example.com or b.example.com... They are totally different domains.

Comment: The problem you are facing is that the cookie with the session token is scoped to a domain. You'll need to solve that first. I don't have a solution for you though.

Answer (score 0):

chose a central place for session store like active record or memcached. Set session secrets same in all apps. 
I have implemented this.. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: It doesn't work for me at all. Could you commit your sample code to github?